# How to avoid to use polling with raspberry?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, listener, infinite-loop, polling

I am doing a project with Raspberry in Java and I use the Pi4j library.
I don't wont use polling, so for example I use this code :

```
public class ListenGpioExample {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("<--Pi4J--> GPIO Listen Example ... started.");

    // create gpio controller
    final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

    // provision gpio pin #02 as an input pin with its internal pull down resistor enabled
    final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

    // create and register gpio pin listener
    myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            // display pin state on console
            System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
        }

    });

    System.out.println(" ... complete the GPIO #02 circuit and see the listener feedback here in the console.");

    // keep program running until user aborts (CTRL-C)
    for (;;) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    // stop all GPIO activity/threads by shutting down the GPIO controller
    // (this method will forcefully shutdown all GPIO monitoring threads and scheduled tasks)
    // gpio.shutdown();   <--- implement this method call if you wish to terminate the Pi4J GPIO controller        
}}
```

My question is : 
the fact that there is the infinite loop is still a form of polling ?

Because I don't understand if the infinite loop is necessary or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not polling. This example uses an event listener, which will fire up once an state change occurs in the GPIO Pin

As you can read on the [Pi4J library page](http://pi4j.com/example/listener.html):

> The listener implementation is based on GPIO hardware interrupts not
>   state polling.

The `for(;;)` is intended for keeping the program alive until the users stops it (as you can read in the comment)